# Unity Input field not setting value on change

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, parameter-passing

I simply want to set a room name using input fields and the fact that it can pass the input through as an argument, but this does not seem to work for some reason.
here is the function that is called
[image: Code][image]

here is the output in the console when typing in the field
[image][image]

why does it send in a blank string?
I followed this tutorial: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdkrjCF0KCo)

Comment: because your parameter is blank

Comment: Try putting InputField as argument for SetRoomName method and drag your InputField to the onValueChange's argument.

Comment: Have you tried it Tarek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a listener (`HostGame.SetRoomName`) you have two sections from which you can choose your functions: `Dynamic string` and `Static Parameters`. Your function should be in both sections:

- Dynaic string     - `SetRoomName`
- Static Parameters - `SetRoomName(string)`

You have to choose the first one if you want to receive as parameter the input field text. The parameter in the second option is whatever you put in the field below `HostGame.SetRoomName` in your first image (in your case blank).

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by creating a reference to the text in "SetRoomName" it's not ideal but works

Comment: You can actually get the input field text passed as a string argument to your function.. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't been explained well but you want to select the top method under dynamic value. If you look at this image, you will see two methods, selecting the bottom (static) one will show the input field as you see but the top (dynamic) one (which is what you want) will show no input field. [image: An example of what to do]